# Creating a "base URL" constant in a React app

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm building some site with React. Being that the address of both my backend API and my images folder might change from one environment to the other, i would like to setup some "constants", that would hold these base addresses. When i was building non-single-page applications with PHP, i would keep a config file in each environment, that held those constants. How can i achieve something like that with React(or any other single page app for that matter...)

I'll note, that i've seen various configurations using process.env, but from what i understand, this is relevant only for Nodejs(am i correct?). My app will be served by Apache PHP.

I cannot just use a relative path, being that the backend might sit on a different host.

One way that i toyed with, is to perform a hack, when the app renders, like this:

```
window.baseURL= window.location.href.includes('local') ? 'http://localhost' : 'something else...'
```

It works, but i feel that this is a ridiculously unprofessional thing to do.

What is the professional way to approach this? If it's of any help, i'm using Webpack(maybe it can access some config file, and setup some global variables..?).

Comment: that shouldn't be part of the react config, but webpack or whatever build system you are using, something like: `publicPath: isProd ? '/' : 'http://localhost:8080/',`

Comment: And how can i use this inside React?

Comment: you don't have to, react should be responsive of from the relative path onward, that means in `https://localhost:3000/categories/react` your server should take care of serving the files from `https://localhost:3000` or `http://example.com`, while react should take care of the relative paths `categories/react` for example.

Comment: I've mentioned that i cannot use a relative path for this: "I cannot just use a relative path, being that the backend might sit on a different host."

Comment: Ok, then is the webpack what you need to tweak.

Comment: I understand..but how..? :D

Comment: https://simonsmith.io/organising-webpack-config-environments/

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you what I do in my projects. I have 2 environments parameters (`NODE_ENV=production` and `NODE_ENV=development` which passed in the build scripts in the package.json file), with the `NODE_ENV` I read the relevant settings.js file, called accordingly (`settings.production.js` / `settings.development.js`), and pull from there all the different parameters according to the current environment.